# No appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I'm getting the following error in my C++ program:

```
1>          c:\users\thom\documents\cworkspace\barnaby\barnaby\timezone.cpp(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
```

This is down a bit in the error stack but points to this line of code:

```
static std::map<const std::string, Timezone>    timezoneMap;
```

The reason is that Timezone has a rather elaborate constructor, but no default constructor. Here's that part of the error:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(215): error C2512: 'Timezone::Timezone' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(210) : while compiling class template member function 'Timezone &std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'

My question is, why? Why is the map trying to construct a Timezone object? Why should it need too if I always put fully formed objects into my map? Especially, why this error when I initialize the map?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're probably using the `map`'s `operator[]` which *does* require the default constructor (if it didn't, how would it handle the case where the key doesn't exist in the map?). If you use `insert` instead you *may* be able to get away with not providing one (I can't recall if the standard requires a default constructor for all maps, or just when you use that operator).

Comment: +1 Good stuff. Note that for `std::map<int, Foo>` with `explicit Foo::Foo(int)` the only constructor and with explicit copy constructor, you can always say `m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 5));`, but you can only say `m.insert(std::make_pair(1, Foo(5)));` in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

The map object needs a default constructor when you access the structure using [] (my previous explanation was so convoluted as to be meaningless - sorry). See: [Why does the C++ map type argument require an empty constructor when using []?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695645/why-does-the-c-map-type-argument-require-an-empty-constructor-when-using)

Comment: This sounds wrong. No objects are created "invisibly". The map only creates an object when you explicitly want it to.

Comment: You're right. I totally didn't say what I mean. @Mark-B did.