# C++ std::map with user defined data type

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

> Implementing class for disjoint sets

---

```
struct Set
{
    int parent,rank;
    Set(int i):parent(i),rank(0){}
    Set(const Set& s2):parent(s2.parent),rank(s2.rank){}
};


struct Disjoint
{
    std::map<int,Set> forest;
    Disjoint(){}
    void init_node(int i)
    {
        forest[i]=Set(i);//error here
    }
};
```

---

> Now after compiling it I see,

/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:458: error: no matching function for call to 'Set::Set()'
note: candidates are:
DU_SET.cpp:13:5: note: Set::Set(const Set&)
DU_SET.cpp:13:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
DU_SET.cpp:12:5: note: Set::Set(int)
DU_SET.cpp:12:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided*

> *I have also implemented the copy constructor for class Set but the same error comes back again.
>   when I implement another constructor with no parameters it works fine but why**

Comment: STL requires default constructor..

Comment: Well, duplicate?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695645/why-does-the-c-map-type-argument-require-an-empty-constructor-when-using

Comment: Say `forest.insert(std::make_pair(i, Set(i)))` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the statement

```
forest[i]=Set(i);
```

the `forest[i]` will try create a `Set` object using the default constructor and placed in that location. Then another will be created using `Set(i)` and will be assigned to the *ith* position using *assignment operator*. hence you have to provide a default constructor.

To avoid it use `std::map::insert` method.

```
forest.insert( {i, Set(i)} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::map::emplace` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)) to construct an object directly in the map:

```
forest.emplace(i, i);
```

Note: First `i` will be used to construct the key, the second `i` will be used to construct the object `Set`.

Comment: That's not what `emplace` does. Rather, it constructs a `value_type` from the arguments. The OP's ill-advised implicit constructor happens to make this work.

Comment: How did I state otherwise? You can also use `emplace(i, Set{i})` if you prefer.

Comment: Well, it sounds dangerously like you're suggesting that the arguments are split somehow between key constructor arguments and mapped-value constructor arguments, but that's not the case. Instead, everything is passed to the `pair` constructor.

Comment: You have to use `std::piecewise_construct` to do the splitting. But if the mapped type can be constructed from one argument it also works without.