# Why is the [] operator of C++ Map calling default constructor of mapped-value?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I compiled the following code with g++, the construct function A() will be called when executing the line:

```
m["1"]
```

Why is this happening? I don't see any necessarily of calling the constructor here.

```
struct A
{
   int mem;
   A(int arg){}
   A(){}
};
int main()
{
   unordered_map<string, A> m;
   m["1"]; // will call A(), but why?
   m.find("1")->second; // will not call A()
}
```

Comment: Because it needs to construct an "empty" object if it doesn't already exist. Else, what could it ***possibly*** return when the specified key doesn't exist?

Comment: The [] operator of a map tries to access the index specified, if it's not found,  it will create one for you at the specified index, setting it to the default value of the mapped value type,  which is calling the constructor in this case

Comment: What should the value of the expression `m["1"]` be?

Comment: However, Even if I write as:  m["1"] = A(1);  A() still will be called.

Comment: @KaiWang Yes, it will, for the exact same reason. There's no problem here whatsoever.

Comment: @KaiWang: Subexpressions are evaluated first.

Comment: @KaiWang: Because `m["1"]` creates a new element and returns a _reference_ to the new element. The `= A(1);` part just assigns a different value to the newly created element. If you don't want that behavior then call `insert()` instead.

Comment: Tempted to close as dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/695645/560648

Answer (score 3):

That's the design of [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/).  If he doesn't find the value you're looking at, the entry is created with default constructor.

If you want to look if an element exists without necessary creating it, you could use [`find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) instead.

If you want to address an element like you do with `operator[]` but throwing an exception if the element is not found instead of creating the missing entry, you would prefer [`at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/)

Comment: Thanks. But even if I write as:  m["1"] = A(1);  A() still will be called.

Comment: @KaiWang, the `operator[]` must return a reference *before* the assignment occurs, so it still has to initialize a location.