# declaring a map with its value type is a class

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am unable to define a map that take an object which i describe in a class as value type. 
I am trying to create a book library with each book is in form of a map with its key is a string (the name of the book) and its value is a class book which holds the data.
Here is my code:

```
class book{
// properties, fields
    string title;
    string author;
    int isbn;
    bool isCheckedOut;
    int dayCheckedOut;
// constructor
book(string title, string author, int isbn){
    title = title;
    author = author;
    isbn = isbn;
    isCheckedOut = false;
    dayCheckedOut = -1;
}
```

and this is where i define my map:

```
class library{
    map<string,book> bookCollection;
    int currentDay;
    int lengthOfCheckOutPeriod;
    float initialLateFee;
    float lateFeePerDay;}
public:
    //constructor
    library(map<string,book> bookCollection){
        bookCollection = bookCollection;}
```

this is the main:

```
int main(){
    map<string,book> bookCollection;
    book harry("Harry Potter","J.K.Rowling",123123);       
    book cal("Calculus","Stewart",456456);
    bookCollection["Harry Potter"]=harry;
    bookCollection["Calculus"]=cal;

    library lib(bookCollection);
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile it raise an error:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(215): error C2512: 'book::book' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(210) : while compiling class template member function 'book &std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::operator [](const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=book,
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          d:\1551036\linh tinh\book library\book library\main.cpp(39) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=book
1>          ]
```

What is wrong with it? Is there any alternative method or structure for this?

Comment: 'book::book' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695645/why-does-the-c-map-type-argument-require-an-empty-constructor-when-using

Comment: FYI the default constructor has no arguments. so in your case book::book()

Comment: ok. it works  now. thank you :)