# Access instance method when object is a <map> value

Tags: c++

What is the correct way to call the `print()` method when accessing `prime` as a value of an std::map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Prime {
private:
    int n;

public:
    Prime(int n): n(n) {}

    Prime(const Prime &P) {
        n = P.n;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "value: " << n << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Prime prime(5);

    map<string, Prime> myMap;
    myMap.emplace("five", prime);

    // this line appears to be failing
    myMap["five"].print();

    return 1;
}
```

When I run this code `$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out`:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:63:0,
                   from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61,
                   from main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0ul}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = Prime]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1079:63:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = Prime]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:140:49:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>::_Rb_tree_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> > >; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from ‘static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> > >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:408:36:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:1669:64:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_hint_unique(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:484:8:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = Prime; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Prime> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Prime; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string<char>]’
main.cpp:31:15:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1090:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘Prime::Prime()’
           second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1090:70: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:15:3: note: Prime::Prime(const Prime&)
     Prime(const Prime &P) {
     ^
main.cpp:15:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:13:3: note: Prime::Prime(int)
     Prime(int n): n(n) {}
     ^
main.cpp:13:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your `print` method - read the error carefully. `std::map` requires your class to have a default constructor

Comment: I see that the error message is that it can't find a constructor with 0 args (default constructor?). However, I am confused as to why std::map needs my class to have a default constructor when I defined a constructor and copy constructor.

Comment: Also, the code compiles when commenting out `myMap["five"].print();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing `Prime(int n = 0): n(n) {}` is your fix.

Even if you are using `emplace`, the `Prime` class is required by the C++ standard to have a default constructor, which yours currently doesn't.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695645/why-does-the-c-map-type-argument-require-an-empty-constructor-when-using for explanation why C++ requires a default constructor

Comment: Not to hijack, but I figured this is more appropriate to ask than it's own question -- is there any difference between `Prime(int n = 0): n(n) {}` and `Print(int n = 0): n{n} {}`?

Comment: @zv_ The second syntax is not valid

Comment: @Antwane I just used it so I'm pretty sure it is (for setting the member variable `n` to the parameter `int n` at least, there may be some other use that isn't valid that I'm not aware of)

Comment: @Antwane the second syntax is uniform initialization and has been valid since C++11.

Comment: Pedantically @zv_ has changed `Prime` to `Print`, which is not syntactially valid since it's now not a constructor.

Comment: @Bathsheba good eyes! I meant to write `Prime(int n = 0): n{n} {}`.