# c++ trying to access an element in a map gives me a no matching function call error to the constructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, default-constructor, function-call

I'm trying to code a simple spreadsheet, but I am having trouble with the update method.

The basic idea is that the spreadsheet class searches it's cell map for the cell with the specified name, and then calls the cell's update method with the new data. However, when I try to compile the code, the line that calls the cell's update method causes a no-matching function call error to the cell contstructor, even though that line does not call the constructor at all.

The map in question is a map with strings as keys and cells, a class I defined for this project, as values.

The specific function I am trying to code is written like this:

```
std::string spreadsheet::update(std::string cellName, std::string data)
{
  //if the cell exists
  if(activeCells.count(cellName) > 0)
  {

     activeCells[cellName].update(data); //removing this line lets the 
                                        //program compile successfully
     return data;
   }
   else
   {
     //make a new cell
     cell newCell(data);
     std::pair<std::string, cell> newItem(cellName, newCell);
     activeCells.insert(newItem);

     return data;
   }
}
```

The specific error I get when I try to compile this looks like so:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_map.h:469:59: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘SAPS::cell::cell()’
>              __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));

(SAPS is the namespace.)

I find this odd, because the error references cell's constructor, but the line that apparently causes the issue doesn't reference cell's constructor at all.

The cell class's constructor looks like this:

```
cell:cell(std::string data)
{
  update(data);
}
```

and the update method looks like this:

```
void cell::update(std::String data)
{
  contents.push(data);
}
```

Contents, in the cell class, is simply a stack of strings.

the cell's h file has function declarations set up like this:

```
cell(std::string data);
~cell();

void update(std::string data);
```

all of which are declared as public functions.

While I didn't think of every possible edge case while testing the cell class, I did confirm that all of the basic functionality works as expected.

I'm probably missing something obvious which is already on the site, but I'm so confused I don't know where, exactly, to look for a solution.

Any and all assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This has something to do with the class definition of whatever the map contains. Since you failed to provide even the most miniscule amount of information about the class, there's no sufficient information for any kind of an answer to be possible. The most likely answer is that the class does not have a default constructor, but that's just a guess. Welcome to stackoverflow.com. You need to take the tour of the [help], and carefully read the instructions for preparing a [mcve].

Comment: I agree with Sam Varshavchik - that's too less information to give a definitive answer. My guess is also that the default constructor for `cell` is missing. See [Why does the C++ map type argument require an empty constructor when using square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695645/2328447)

Comment: Ok, I have added some of the cell class functions. Sorry for not adding them earlier; I assumed that my problem was elsewhere, as the cell class worked properly according to my last test. I'll add in some more edge cases to be sure.

Comment: Wait, actually, that's probably it: no default constructor. I didn't have one because I never intended to initialize cell without a value. I will add one real quick and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the issue was Cell's lack of a default constructor. I had forgotten that map and many similar functions require such a constructor. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

It seems the takeaway here is to always add a default constructor, even if you don't plan on using it.

Comment: right, `map::operator[]` will create an instance for that key if it doesn't exist, and it does that via the default constructor. You can use `map` for classes without a default constructor, but you have to use functions like `.at()` and `.insert()` to do what you need to do.