# Insert or update into an unordered_map without requiring a default constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, unordered-map, default-constructor

I have a `std::unordered_map` to which I want to add a key-value pair. If the key does not yet exist, then I want it to be added with the given value. If the key already exists, then I want the value to be updated.

The standard advice here, it seems, is to use `operator[]`. But this requires the value type of the map to be default-constructible. I wish to avoid providing a default constructor. What should I do?

Comment: not sure where you got the advice, but I have it kinda reversed: only if you want a default constructed value for a new key, then `operator[]` is the right function to call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `insert_or_assign` (C++17)

As indicated on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign) you don't need to have default construtible objects in that case:

> insert_or_assign returns more information than operator[] and does not require default-constructibility of the mapped type.

Comment: I swear I looked at the list of methods and did not see this. I am blind, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: oh, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/ doesn't list this method. That is why I did not see it.

Comment: It's C++17, that may be why? I added the info in my answer.

Comment: @hammerite you just found one reason to switch to a different reference ;) cppreference isnt perfect either, but better

Comment: I have a shortcut for searching starting with `-site:www.cpluscplus.com -site:cplusplus.com` since the `C++ Reference` in that sites title often leads me to waste a click.

Comment: @Hammerite Better use cppreference as cplusplus.com is known to often contain wrong or incomplete information.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign for map, probably there is similar link for unordered

Comment: That's the link I gave... What's the point of your comment?