# STL container for objects with references

Tags: c++, stl

Consider to the following code:

```
class C
{
public:
    C(int &a):_a(a){}
private:
    int &_a;
};
```

Because of the reference to _a, this object can not be contained as value in an STL container.
A default constructor cannot be added to this class because of this reference.

Is there a way to make this object fit into an STL container without changing the reference to a pointer?

Ideally, I think I would like to use some sort of std::reference_wrapper for it, but I can't because it is not default constructible itself.

Comment: `any_container<std::unique_ptr<C>>`?

Comment: You don't need default constructible types for STL containers (some methods might require it).

Comment: "but I can't because it is not default constructible itself." default constructible is not a requirement for standard containers

Comment: Due to your own answer, it is a duplicate to [Why does the C++ map type argument require an empty constructor when using \[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695645/why-does-the-c-map-type-argument-require-an-empty-constructor-when-using)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make this object fit into an STL container

Certainly:

```
std::vector<C> name_of_vector {
    some_int, another_int, ...
};
```

Note that the implicitly generated assignment operator of `C` has semantics that have potentially unexpected consequences if `std::vector<C>` is reallocated. Namely, the assignment operator modifies the referred integer.

I would strongly advice to define the assignment operator as deleted. Even better, avoid using reference members entirely.

> Ideally, I think I would like to use some sort of std::reference_wrapper

This would likely be a more reasonable choice due to its assignment semantics (it re-binds rather than modifies the referred object).

> but I can't because it is not default constructible itself.

Default constructibility is not a requirement for element of any standard container (although it is requirement of some member functions of some standard containers, so are limited to not using those).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't work is because I was trying to insert into an unordered_map using the [] operator.

This is the reason the compiler complained about a missing default constructor.

I just forgot that [] meant "find or create" and doesn't work like insert.
Using insert solved the problem